# "The BEST answers are voted up and rise to the top" or "The MOST POPULAR answers are voted up and rise to the top"?

Tags: discussion, up-votes, wording

The banner at the top of each Stack Exchange site says "The best answers are voted up and rise to the top". Would it be better to say "The most popular answers are voted up and rise to the top"?

Upvotes mean an answer is popular. Upvotes do not necessarily mean an answer is good, or even correct.

I am not saying that "The most popular answers..." is perfect (e.g., the accepted answer also rises to the top). But I think it would be more accurate, while still being clear and concise, and thus better, than "The best answers..."

Comment: @RobertLongson I agree. Do you think "the best answers..." is a better choice than "the most popular answers..."? If so, why?

Comment: Accepted answers are not always the most popular ones.

Comment: @convert absolutely, they are one person's opinion and that person presumably isn't an expert either but that's not we're talking about here is it?

Comment: @convert They aren't always voted up either, nor (on many sites) do they even rise to the top any more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure there may be occasional exceptions but for the most part [the concept of the wisdom of crowds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wisdom_of_Crowds) would suggest that the most popular answers are generally also the best.

If we said most popular that would simply beg the question as to why they became most popular. Best is much simpler and easier for someone who's coming across these sites for the first time to understand. Best = try that one first.